# Function Spaces in Topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have a question... Is discrete topology  admissible ?

I tried using that evaluation is continuos but i stuck , some help please.

Comment: What do you mean by admissible topology... ?

Comment: sorry a tried to say that is admissible topology iff evaluation map is continuos

Comment: When the topology is discrete, any map is continuous.

Comment: Are you asking whether the discrete topology on $C(X)$ (the space of continuous real valued functions on $X$) is admissible in the sense of Arens (that the function $C(X) \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\langle f,x \rangle \mapsto f(x)$ is continuous)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be your space of functions (say continuous functions, or all functions etc.) on some space $X$ to some space $Y$. The function $e$ (evaluation) is defined on $\mathcal{F} \times X$ to $Y$, by $e(f,x) = f(x)$. A topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $\mathcal{F}$ is admissible iff $e$ is a continuous map (in the respective topologies on $Y$ and the product topology of $\mathcal{T}$ and the topology of $X$).

If we take $\mathcal{T}$ to be discrete, the product topology on $\mathcal{F} \times X$ just reduces to the sum topology on $|\mathcal{F}|$ copies of $X$: a set $O \subset \mathcal{F} \times X$ is open iff for every $f \in \mathcal{F}$, $O_f = \{x \in X: (f,x) \in O \}$ is open in $X$.

So if $V \subset Y $ is open, $e^{-1}[V]$ is open iff for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$ the set $\{x \in X: (f,x) \in e^{-1}[V] \} = \{x \in X: e(f,x) \in V \} = \{x \in X: f(x) \in V \} = f^{-1}[V]$ is open in $X$. So indeed $e^{-1}[V]$ is open iff $\mathcal{F} \subset C(X,Y)$, i.e. all members of $\mathcal{F}$ are themselves continuous between $X$ and $Y$ (which is probably the case, but wasn't stated explicitly).

So in short, if we are working on the set of all continuous functions between $X$ and $Y$ (or a subset thereof) then the discrete topology on that function space is admissible in this sense.

Answer (score 1):

Every set in the discrete topology is open, so the inverse image of an open set in the range is obviously an open set, since every set is open. Thus every function out of a discrete space is continuous.